# Album art not appearing

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

i m trying to get album art but album art doesnt appear when app runs.i dont know whats wrog with this.please help me with this.tried many solution on internet but couldnt get this.
this is my logs.

> No adapter attached; skipping layout 01-11 13:46:27.310
>   809-809/com.example.murarilal.atry I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!
>   The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 01-11
>   13:46:27.348 809-840/com.example.murarilal.atry D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3b850c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3b831e0) 01

```
  private void loadSongs() {
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
             cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                        long albumId = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                        songInfo s = new songInfo(name, artist, url,albumId);
                        _songs.add(s);
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

public class songInfo {
    private String SongName;
    private String ArtistName;
    private String SongUrl;
    private long album_art;

    public songInfo() {
    }

    public songInfo(String songname, String artistname, String songUrl, long album) {
        SongName = songname;
        ArtistName = artistname;
        SongUrl = songUrl;
        album_art=album;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return SongName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        SongName = songName;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return ArtistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        ArtistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getSongUrl() {
        return SongUrl;
    }
    public long getAlbum_art() {
        return album_art;
    }



    public void setSongUrl(String songUrl) {
        SongUrl = songUrl;
    }

}



 my adapter



public  class songAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<songAdapter.SongHolder>{

    private ArrayList<songInfo> _songs = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    Cursor cursorm;

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public songAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<songInfo> songs) {
        this.context = context;
        this._songs = songs;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, songInfo obj, int position);

        // void onItemClick(Button b, View view, songInfo obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }


    @Override
    public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card,viewGroup,false);
        return new SongHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {
        final songInfo s = _songs.get(i);
       /* cursorm =context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)},
                null);
        String albumId = cursorm.getString(cursorm.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

        if (cursorm != null && cursorm.moveToFirst()) {
            String path = cursorm.getString(cursorm.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
            Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
            songHolder.album_art.setImageDrawable(img);
        }*/
        songHolder.album_art.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(String.valueOf(_songs.get(i).getAlbum_art())));
        songHolder.tvSongName.setText(_songs.get(i).getSongName());
        songHolder.tvSongArtist.setText(_songs.get(i).getArtistName());
        setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, songInfo obj, int position) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder, view, s, i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _songs.size();
    }

    public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSongName,tvSongArtist;
        ImageView album_art;
        public SongHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSongName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
            tvSongArtist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            album_art = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumArt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got null pointer exception on this line:

```
String albumId = cursorm.getString(cursorm.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
```

your `Cursor` `cursorm` is never initialized before. You are initializing your `cursor` just after the above line. Check your initialization of `cursorm` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Error is occurring because you use cursorm before initializing. You call this line before setting it in the next line.

```
String albumId = cursorm.getString(cursorm.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
```

P.S.- Form my understanding you are trying to show the album art of each song. To do that, Store albumId in SongInfo and get it from ArrayList instead of collecting albumId from MediaStore for each song.

Comment: how it should be in above example

Comment: Here is one of my projects  https://github.com/UdeshUK/CoffeeMusicPlayer . It's a player. It might help you.